# Where is a join processed when dealing with a linked server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the example from SQL Server to [join tables from a linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16#join-tables-from-a-linked-server), it gives the following eample:

```
SELECT local.name AS LocalLogins, linked.name AS LinkedLogins  
FROM master.sys.server_principals AS local  
LEFT JOIN [SRVR002\ACCTG].master.sys.server_principals AS linked  
     ON local.name = linked.name;  
GO
```

How is the data passed back and forth between the two servers and where is the processing done? For example, does SQLServer run the following steps:

1. Do `SELECT linked.name FROM [SRVR002\ACCTG].master.sys.server_principals`
2. Send the data back over the network to the local/master SQLServer, and for example, load that into a tmp table.
3. Finish the query locally, for example:

```
SELECT local.name AS LocalLogins, linked.name AS LinkedLogins  
FROM master.sys.server_principals AS local  
LEFT JOIN tmp AS linked ON local.name = linked.name;
```

Or how actually is the query executed?

Comment: It depends on how much data SQL Server thinks is on each side. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2765/revisit-your-use-of-the-sql-server-remote-join-hint/?utm_source=AaronBertrand

Comment: @AaronBertrand I see, so it's more like an "it depends", and sometimes SQL Server won't even be able to know how much data is on the other server without a hint. Is the above procedure I've listed though a "possible way" that SQL Server might do the join?

Comment: At a very high level, yes. SQL Server has to decide _where to process the join_ and will have to sometimes guess if it is cheaper to shuffle rows remotely, do the join there, and then bring the results, or bring the remote rows local, and perform the join here. I wouldn't get too specific about whether it uses a temp table, though.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I see, do you know if SQL Server is able to read the stats/information_schema from other databases (such as Oracle or Postgres) to be able to make this determination? Or is the only way if it's outside the SQL Server ecosystem to manually provide the 'hints' ?

Comment: Sorry, no, will have to leave that for others. I have never played with either of those platforms in this capacity.